# filling missing values with mean/max of previous 16 days values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, zoo

I have a time series dataset as given:

```
d1<- structure(list(date = c("8/11/2020", "8/7/2020", "8/4/2020", 
"7/28/2020", "7/27/2020", "7/23/2020", "7/20/2020", "7/13/2020", 
"7/8/2020", "6/25/2020", "6/24/2020", "6/23/2020", "6/18/2020", 
"6/15/2020", "6/10/2020", "6/9/2020", "6/8/2020", "6/5/2020", 
"6/3/2020", "6/1/2020", "5/31/2020", "5/24/2020", "5/21/2020", 
"5/14/2020", "5/11/2020", "5/9/2020", "5/8/2020", "5/7/2020", 
"5/4/2020", "4/22/2020", "4/21/2020", "4/16/2020", "4/14/2020", 
"4/9/2020", "4/6/2020", "4/5/2020"), x = c(-3.444434096, -5.554643467, 
-5.819128168, -6.528574452, -6.528574452, -8.59555826, -3.025536602, 
-2.698376659, -3.483474963, -7.696235263, NA, -7.572170935, -7.185040842, 
-7.492766547, -3.728460293, -7.773342378, -7.773342378, NA, -6.601276462, 
NA, -6.315658227, -5.421106712, -5.421106712, -2.3212135, -3.40345796, 
-2.942817915, -2.942817915, NA, -1.858551108, -0.264005923, -0.264005923, 
0.192899359, -0.204841155, -0.107794142, -0.087664372, NA), y = c(-0.095663228, 
-2.228724135, NA, -1.287448285, -2.090320147, -2.090320147, 1.269873112, 
-2.64716097, -2.680828961, -2.335090584, -4.117893947, 0.375126608, 
0.375126608, NA, -3.939176552, NA, -1.797405353, -5.27192525, 
-5.27192525, -4.937367195, -4.885790778, -5.611024982, -5.215911023, 
-9.277147196, -9.277147196, -4.896429851, -7.053994787, 1.022381641, 
-1.398690039, 0.058918339, 0.058918339, -1.900802177, -1.253476157, 
1.283432302, 0.519769206, 0.519769206)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-36L))
```

Now, I want to fill those `NA` of variable x using the mean value of previous 16 days (not the previous 15 observations rather 16 days with respect to the date). In addition, I want to fill the `NA` values of variable y using max values of 16 days (considering the previous 7 days and after 7 days). I was trying to do that using dplyr package but couldn't

can I do this in dplyr or tidyr? or any other package or base r code?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `dplyr`s `group_modify` function.

**Code**

```
library(tidyverse)

d1 <- d1 %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")) 

d2 <- d1 %>%
  group_by(row = row_number()) %>%
  group_modify(~{
    .x %>% 
      mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(x),
                        d1 %>% 
                          filter(between(date, .x$date - 16, .x$date)) %>% 
                          summarise(res = mean(x, na.rm = T)) %>%
                          pull(res),
                        x),
             y = ifelse(is.na(y),
                        d1  %>% 
                          filter(between(date, .x$date - 7, .x$date + 7)) %>% 
                          summarise(res = max(y, na.rm = T)) %>%
                          pull(res),
                      y))
  }) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-row)
```

**Output of the first 20 rows**

```
# A tibble: 20 x 3
   date           x       y
   <date>     <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 2020-08-11 -3.44 -0.0957
 2 2020-08-07 -5.55 -2.23  
 3 2020-08-04 -5.82 -0.0957
 4 2020-07-28 -6.53 -1.29  
 5 2020-07-27 -6.53 -2.09  
 6 2020-07-23 -8.60 -2.09  
 7 2020-07-20 -3.03  1.27  
 8 2020-07-13 -2.70 -2.65  
 9 2020-07-08 -3.48 -2.68  
10 2020-06-25 -7.70 -2.34  
11 2020-06-24 -6.92 -4.12  
12 2020-06-23 -7.57  0.375 
13 2020-06-18 -7.19  0.375 
14 2020-06-15 -7.49  0.375 
15 2020-06-10 -3.73 -3.94  
16 2020-06-09 -7.77 -1.80  
17 2020-06-08 -7.77 -1.80  
18 2020-06-05 -5.94 -5.27  
19 2020-06-03 -6.60 -5.27  
20 2020-06-01 -5.72 -4.94
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this perfect solution. Really appreciated !!!! @tamtam